# which spark version is used on EMR if you pass SPARK_HOME

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

Assume we use EMR 6.5.0 which ships with Spark 3.1.2.

If we download the PySpark Python library 2.3.3 and submit the spark application normally, it will run on the EMR Spark default which is 3.1.2.

If you explicitly set SPARK_HOME to be where the pyspark library is (~/.python3.7/site-packages/pyspark) that has 2.3.3, and submit the spark application, will it run against the PySpark 2.3.3 version that ships with the PySpark Python package or still run against the system default which is 3.1.2?